# Proper way to load listbox with images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a scenario that I have a list box with images. 
I have loaded the images in list  box,but list box is loading so slowly.

I want a faster way to load listbox. Again when I am loading list box second time it is also slows down app. But is there any way to store images somewhere
in isolated storage or anywhere, so that when it is loaded second time it can be loaded so fastly.

As a whole I want a faster way to load list box images. Here is my code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    getImages();

}
public void getImages()
{
    try
    {
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());//out of memory exception
            img mediaImage = new img();
            mediaImage.Imgs = image;
            imageList.Items.Add(mediaImage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
public class img
{
    public img()
    { }
    public BitmapImage Imgs { get; set; }
}
```

in Xaml...

```
<ScrollViewer Name="sc" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,422,0,43">
        <ListBox Name="imageList" SelectionChanged="imageList_SelectionChanged_1" Height="126">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="10" Name="image1" Source="{Binding Imgs}" Height="150" Width="150"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

1. So please tell me how to load images fastly.
2. Also loading page second time or clickling back button, in `getimages()` method in `picture.getimage()` it is showing `OutOfOemoryException`(I have written in code).

Comment: Don't put a `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewier`, use `LongListSelector` instead of `ListBox`, and resize the images before display them.

Comment: Hey Neil,Thanks for replying..I want to know how can I bind media library images in longlist Selector with the above given data .I have tried using longlist selector instead of listbox but it is giving invalid cast exception.please give me some code.Pls help me.....